# Unable to extend .d.ts definition

Tags: typescript

```
//-->node_modules/kvl/lib/index.d.ts
declare namespace kvl{
 interface Request{}
 interface Resoinse{}
}
export defaukt kvl;
```

I want to add a method to kvl,

```
//-->src/index.d.ts
import Kvl from 'kvl'

export declare namespace Kvl {
    interface cc {
        intsr: string
    }
}
```

But

```
import Kvl from 'kvl';
const testBug: Kvl.cc = { intsr: 'aaaaa' }
```

[Namespace 'kvl' has no exported member 'cc'.]

Comment: Hi **do not** post code as images.  See 
 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: sorry,It’s the code now.